# Where is the sample applications in the lastest Spring release(Spring Framework 3.0.2)?

Tags: spring, download

On the [Spring download page](http://www.springsource.org/download), It says that

> For all Spring Framework releases, the
> basic release contains only the
> binaries while the -with-dependencies
> release contains everything the basic
> release contains plus all third-party
> dependencies, buildable source trees,
> ***and sample applications***.

When I download the ***spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies.zip***, after extract it I get a list of folders:

```
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\com.bea.commonj
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\com.caucho
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\com.google.jarjar
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\com.h2database
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\com.ibm.websphere
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\com.jamonapi
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\com.lowagie.text
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\com.mchange.c3p0
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\com.opensymphony.quartz
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\com.oracle.toplink.essentials
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\com.springsource.bundlor
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\com.springsource.util
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\com.sun.msv
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\com.sun.syndication
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\com.sun.xml
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\com.thoughtworks.xstream
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\edu.emory.mathcs.backport
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\edu.oswego.cs.concurrent
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\javax.activation
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\javax.annotation
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\javax.ejb
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\javax.el
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\javax.faces
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\javax.inject
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\javax.jdo
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\javax.jms
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\javax.mail
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\javax.persistence
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\javax.portlet
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\javax.resource
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\javax.servlet
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\javax.transaction
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\javax.validation
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\javax.xml.bind
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\javax.xml.rpc
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\javax.xml.soap
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\javax.xml.stream
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\javax.xml.ws
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\net.sourceforge.cglib
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\net.sourceforge.ehcache
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\net.sourceforge.iso-relax
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\net.sourceforge.jasperreports
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\net.sourceforge.jexcelapi
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\net.sourceforge.jibx
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\net.sourceforge.serp
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\net.sourceforge.xslthl
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\org.antlr
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\org.aopalliance
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\org.apache.axis
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\org.apache.bcel
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\org.apache.catalina
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\org.apache.commons
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\org.apache.coyote
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\org.apache.derby
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\org.apache.ibatis
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\org.apache.juli
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\org.apache.log4j
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\org.apache.openjpa
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\org.apache.poi
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\org.apache.regexp
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\org.apache.struts
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\org.apache.taglibs
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\org.apache.tiles
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\org.apache.velocity
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\org.apache.xerces
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\org.apache.xml
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\org.apache.xmlbeans
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\org.apache.xmlcommons
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\org.aspectj
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\org.beanshell
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\org.codehaus.castor
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\org.codehaus.groovy
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\org.codehaus.jackson
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\org.codehaus.jettison
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\org.codehaus.woodstox
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\org.custommonkey.xmlunit
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\org.dom4j
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\org.easymock
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\org.eclipse.jdt
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\org.eclipse.persistence
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\org.freemarker
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\org.hibernate
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\org.hsqldb
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\org.jaxen
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\org.jboss.javassist
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\org.jboss.logging
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\org.jboss.util
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\org.jboss.vfs
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\org.jdom
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\org.jgroups
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\org.joda
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\org.jruby
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\org.junit
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\org.jvnet.staxex
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\org.mortbay.jetty
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\org.mozilla.javascript
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\org.objectweb.asm
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\org.osgi
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\org.relaxng
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\org.slf4j
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\org.springframework
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\org.springframework.build
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\org.testng
I:\soft\java\spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies\org.xmlpull
```

So where are the sample applications? I know one of the sample applications is called ***jpetstore*** in spring 2.0. I did search in these folders and can't find anything useful. By the way, I also download the basic release which is ***spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE.zip***. In the ***readme.txt*** of the basic release I found the following text:

> 4. GETTING STARTED
>
> Please consult the blog examples at
> http://blog.springsource.com as well
> as the sections of interest in the
> reference documentation. ***Sample
> applications and related material will
> be provided as separate downloads***.

But I still don't know where to download the sample applications. Anyone can help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only place I know of is the spring site:

- https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/

Answer (score 0):

Check github.com, you may get one